# Site in closed beta but api working

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

Webapps has been added yesterday, website is in closed beta and it's not possible to see something on the website when you are not logged.
But if you use the API you can get information.

http://api.webapps.stackexchange.com/0.9/questions

In this wanted ?

In this case why don't let the website available in RO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

The site being closed beta prevents people from *participating* so as to prove that the committers are actually, well, committed.

Being able to read data out doesn't allow participation, so we figured why not allow it.